# Markov chains: Condtitional independence implies independence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, independence

In one proof, I encountered the following reasoning:
$$P(T_1=n,T_2=m\mid X_0=j)=P(T_1=n\mid X_0=j)P(T_2=m\mid X_0=j)$$
Where $T$s are waiting times between returns to a state, $X_0$ is the state at time $0$.

The text then goes on saying "thus $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent".

Now, in general, conditional independence does not imply independence, so why is it true in this case?

**edit**: assuming the chain actually enters the states, otherwise they might not be independent at all!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but $T_i=\tau_j(i)-\tau_j(i-1)$ where $\tau_j(i)$ is the time of i-th return to the state $j$

Comment: I see, pardon I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: Edited, hopefully making the question clearer

Comment: Independent with respect to the probability measure $P(\ \mid X_0=j)$, that is. Or, equivalently, independent conditionally on $[X_0=j]$, with respect to $P$.

Comment: @Did well that's the thing, the text was proving independence that way. Or at least that's what I thought months ago. I do not have the text at hand right now, but this is still an unresolved question in my mind, will revisit it as soon as I get home. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The text is correct.

Comment: Oh, right! I will re-read the theorem and then your comment and see if it will then make sense.